# Dummy Linux user for installing programs

Tags: linux, partitioning, user-accounts

I have a separate home partition, so I want to install some software from source in a different hierarchy – not in my user account, preferably in `/home`.

To rephrase, let's say I have my home directory in `/home/myuser` and I want my new hierarchy (i.e. `/bin, /lib, /include, /share, /local, /src` nested in a dummy user's directory – say `/home/myprograms` so that all the software I install from source or just want to install away from /usr can reside in a separate directory.

I can install programs in that directory, but how do I make those programs available to all users on my PC?

If anyone has a different suggestion for maintaining two hierarchies, please also leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The convention for 3rd party programs is to install them under `/usr/local` which is will make them available to other users (on most distributions).

You could of course use any other directory such as `/home/myuser`, but you'll have to update the `PATH` environment variable. You can do this by creating `/etc/profile.d/mypath.sh` with the following content:

```
PATH="/home/myuser/bin:$PATH"
```

Another choice would be installing them under `/opt` using a subdirectory for each program like this: `/opt/foo/{bin,lib,share}`, `/opt/bar/{bin,lib,share}` and so on. This has the advantage of being able to quickly remove or copy a program's installation, but it has the disadvantage of having everything split up into multiple places, so you'll have to add multiple directories to `PATH`.

For more details read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).